# How to make silmutanuous jquery Ajax calls firing from different events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am having  an issue, developing a page that populates its contents by making several Ajax calls using jquery, 
The problem is that each call has to wait for the present Ajax call to finish before it starts which makes the page load so slow.

I want all the Ajax calls to start without waiting for the other.

I know of $.when() but the problem is that I cannot pass all the calls  into a single $.when() because they are all initiated by different individual events and functions.

Comment: Can you should an example?  Ajax normally runs async, so they should all run at the same time.  How have you implemented it so that each waits for the previous?

Comment: "*The problem is that each call has to wait for the present Ajax call to finish before it starts*"  Why?  This statement suggests that you have some logic that requires the statements to run sequentially.  Giving them all to a `$.when()` would be problematic if that is the case.  You would need to make each call independent for them all to be safely given to a `$.when()`.

Comment: Ajax: **Asyncronous** JavaScript + XML

Comment: Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for help on asking questions here. And welcome to stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem.
The problem was not coming from jquery ajax call, but from my own function.

I have a function like this

```
function perform_ajax(url,parameters,callback){
  //codes to perform jquery ajax here
}
```

so if I have another set of codes like

```
perform_ajax(url1,parameter1,callback1);
perform_ajax(url2,parameter2,callback2);
perform_ajax(url3,parameter3,callback3);
```

the three codes executes synchronously because they are refering to the same function...
I solved this issue by using

```
async function perform_ajax(url,parameter,callback){
//codes to perform jquery ajax calls
}
```

But the issue i have with this is backward compactibility.

Is there a way I can check if a browser supports **async function** before defining the function?

Answer (score -1):

try to set

```
 $.ajax({
        async:true,
        ....
})
```

JQuery Documentation  [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

> async (default: true) Type: Boolean By default, all requests are sent
>   asynchronously (i.e. this is set to true by default). If you need
>   synchronous requests, set this option to false. Cross-domain requests
>   and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not support synchronous operation.
>   Note that synchronous requests may temporarily lock the browser,
>   disabling any actions while the request is active. As of jQuery 1.8,
>   the use of async: false with jqXHR ($.Deferred) is deprecated; you
>   must use the success/error/complete callback options instead of the
>   corresponding methods of the jqXHR object such as jqXHR.done().

Comment: This answer isn't wrong but, since this is the default behavior, this probably isn't the cause of their problem

Comment: Unless they set async: false by default. Unlikely, but this answer can hint the place where they should check.

Comment: I know, but if he does not write any code, I do not know if he had 'async' false or true